# Update to Gradle 5.1.1 gives "The ProjectLayout.fileProperty() method has been deprecated"

Tags: android, gradle

I am working on a project that previously used Gradle 4.6 and it worked fine. I just updated to Gradle 5.1.1 and I am now receiving the following warnings (Not sure they are warnings or errors, though):

```
> Configure project :app
Warning: Please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
The ProjectLayout.fileProperty() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0. Please use the ObjectFactory.fileProperty() method instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to notify build listener.
> org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl.getModuleIdentifier()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleIdentifier;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 0s
Cause: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl.getModuleIdentifier()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleIdentifier;
```

I searched for ProjectLayout.fileProperty inside the whole project and didn't find a single string like that. Where is fileProperty used then causing the compiler to complain? How can I fix these deprecation warnings rather than suppressing them? Is there a part of my code I need to change? Or does the usage pointed to by compiler occur inside one of the libraries I have added?

Comment: https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/issues/1307

Answer (score 2):

These are warnings, not errors, and can come either from your own build scripts, or as it seems to be the case here, from a plugin.
These warnings, as they indicate, can become errors *only* when moving to the next Gradle major version.

- In the case the source of the warning is inside your build script, you should try to make them go away as fast as possible. That way upgrading to the next Gradle major version will not be a problem.
- When coming from a plugin, if you can identify the right plugin, upgrade to a more recent version and file an issue if the warning persists. This way you have a better chance that the plugin keeps working with the next Gradle major version.